# Heuristics for the travelling salesman

Tags: genetic-algorithm, heuristics, traveling-salesman, evolutionary-algorithm

I am working on evolutionary optimization and on this project I need 
heuristics for the travelling salesman problem. In this context,
genetic algorithms, we apply small mutations and hope that somewhere
down the road things will get better. So, I am looking for simple heuristics
for transforming the solution that could potentially lead to improvement.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for tour improvement heuristic and I can suggest that [Lin-Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernighan%E2%80%93Lin_algorithm) algorithm for you. But this algorithm may be too difficult for you. So instead you can research [2-opt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt) or 3-opt algorithm.

Comment: 2-opt is just reversing locations in a tour. But what is interesting from the 2-opt article on wikipedia is the way it applies this. It tries several possible options and picks the one that minimizes the path cost. I can do this same thing with many other operations like sorting, shuffling, reversing, shifting, etc. The 3-opt is very interesting though. Thank you! If I have time left I will also look at Kernighan–Lin algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

One reference that I want to recommend is [R's TSP package](http://tsp.r-forge.r-project.org/). (Do look into it even if you are not using R.)
[Their vignette on TSP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSP/vignettes/TSP.pdf) is excellent, and has lots of Dynamic Programming based tricks that you can try to improve your GA implementation.

*Section 2.4* of the vignette in particular talks of **Tour construction heuristics** that you can incorporate. Quoting from that:

> **Nearest neighbor algorithm**: follows a very simple greedy procedure: The algorithm starts with a tour containing a randomly
>   chosen city and then always adds to the last city in the tour the
>   nearest not yet visited city. The algorithm stops when all cities are
>   on the tour.
>
> An extension to this algorithm is to repeat it with each city as the
>   starting point and then return the best tour found. This heuristic is
>   called repetitive nearest neighbor.
>
> **Insertion algorithms.** start with a tour consisting of an arbitrary city and then choose in each step a city not yet on the tour. This
>   city is inserted into the existing tour between two consecutive cities
>   i and j, such that the insertion cost (i.e., the increase in the
>   tour's length) is minimized. The algorithms stop when all cities are
>   on the tour.
>
> **Nearest insertion** The city k is chosen in each step as the city which is nearest to a city on the tour.
>
> **Farthest insertion** The city k is chosen in each step as the city which is farthest from any of the cities on the tour.
>
> **Cheapest insertion** The city k is chosen in each step such that the cost of inserting the new city is minimal.

You can find a lot more detail and other techniques mentioned in the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSP/vignettes/TSP.pdf).